# Gutenberg Block with JSON Data

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a custom gutenberg block which shall display a description, whatever blocks I put into it and most importantly custom json.

```js
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks
const {
    RichText,
    InspectorControls,
    MediaUpload,
    InnerBlocks
} = wp.blockEditor
const {
    PanelBody,
    IconButton,
} = wp.components
const { select } = wp.data

registerBlockType('exampletheme/article-block', {
    title: 'Artikel Block',
    description: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    icon: 'format-image',
    category: 'example-blocks',
    attributes: {
        image: {
            type: 'string',
            default: null
        },
        description: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'head p'
        }
    },
    edit: ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
        const {
            image,
            description
        } = attributes

        function updateImage(value) {
            setAttributes({ image: value })
        }
        function updateDescription(value) {
            setAttributes({ description: value })
        }
        return ([
            <InspectorControls style={{ marginBottom: '40px' }} >
                <PanelBody title="Blockeinstellungen">
                    <p><strong>Bildeinstellungen</strong></p>
                    <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={updateImage}
                        type="image"
                        value={image}
                        render={({ open }) => (
                            <IconButton
                                onClick={open}
                                icon="upload"
                                className="editor-media-placeholder__button is-button is-default is-large"
                            >
                                Bild
                                </IconButton>
                        )}
                    />
                    <br />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>,
            <article>
                {image &&
                    <img src={image.sizes.large.url} alt={image.alt} title={image.title} />
                }
                <RichText
                    key="editable"
                    tagName="p"
                    placeholder="Kurzbeschreibung des Artikels"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={updateDescription}
                />
                <main>
                    <InnerBlocks />
                </main>
            </article>
        ])
    },
    save: ({ attributes }) => {
        const {
            image,
            description
        } = attributes
        function json() {
            const headline = wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPost().title
            const imgUrl = image ? image.sizes.full.url : ''
            const datePub = wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostAttribute('date')
            const authorName = wp.data.select('core').getCurrentUser.name
            return `
                {myJsonString}
            `
        }
        return (
            <article>
                <head>
                    {image &&
                        <picture>
                            <source media="(max-width: 150px)" srcset={image.sizes.thumbnail.url} />
                            <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset={image.sizes.medium.url} />
                            <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset={image.sizes.large.url} /> */}
                        <img src={image.url} alt={image.alt} title={image.title} />
                        </picture>
                    }
                    <h1>{wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPost().title}</h1>
                    <RichText.Content
                        tagName="p"
                        value={description}
                    />
                </head>
                <main>
                    <InnerBlocks.Content />
                </main>
                {/* <script type="application/ld+json">{json()}</script> */}
            </article >
        )
    }
})
```

I get the following error in my console. For readability I turned the json off, but it has the same problem. I can't figure out why it differs like that.

```
Content generated by `save` function:

<article class="wp-block-myrmodtheme-article-block"><head><h1></h1><p></p></head><main></main></article>

Content retrieved from post body:

<article class="wp-block-myrmodtheme-article-block"><head><h1>test</h1><p>asdf</p></head><main></main></article>
```

My only guess is, that it might be because of some missconfiguration of the attributes. But they seem totally right for me.

If you could point me to the right direction, that would be awesome. I'm trying to get this working all day long.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

This problem is almost because you have registered your block and then created a page using this block then you modified your save function or attributes.
You should provide deprecated array to list the changes that you made so Gutenberg know you have changed your configuration. 
Further more documentation about deprecated blocks is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-deprecation/)